# Choosing a team of $8$ from $11$ men and $7$ women

Tags: combinatorics

> A team of eight is chosen from $11$ men and $7$ women. How many different teams are possible if there must be at least two women on the team?

My reasoning is that there are $7\choose 2$ ways of selecting $2$ women from the available $7$, and then there are $16 \choose 6$ ways of selecting the remaining $6$ from the available $16$; however, this yields an incorrect number. Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

The correct answer is $18 \choose 8$ $–$ $11\choose8$$7\choose 0$ $–$ $11 \choose 7$$7\choose 1$, which makes sense. However, I am confused at how my approach does not achieve the correct answer.

Comment: Your method over counts.  If we choose $W_1,W_2$ as the first two women and later choose $W_3$, that's the same as first choosing $W_1,W_3$ and later $W_2$.

Comment: The given answer comes from counting the number of ways with exactly one woman on the team, and with no women on the team, and then subtract those for the total number of ways to select a team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your approach, you count some events more than once. Let's say the names of the women are $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$.

Then, selecting $A,B,C$ and $5$ men is counted as:

- selecting $A,B$, and then selecting $C$ among the $6$ remaining choices
- selecting $A,C$, and then selecting $B$ among the $6$ remaining choices
- selecting $B,C$, and then selecting $A$ among the $6$ remaining choices

So, you count this event three times, but it is a single event.